# Determinants of $3\times 3$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $a,b,c,d,e,f$  are numbers such that 
$$\det\left(\begin{matrix}
a&1&d\\b&1&e\\ c&1&f
\end{matrix}\right)=7$$ and 
$$\det\left(\begin{matrix}
a&1&d\\b&2&e\\ c&3&f
\end{matrix}\right)=11.$$

How do you find the determinant of the Matrix 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a&3&d\\b&5&e\\ c&7&f
\end{pmatrix}?$$

Any suggestions on how to approach the question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you describe the matrices by lines or columns?

Comment: Matrices equal to numbers? I thought this was only true for $1\times 1$ matrices...

Comment: Judging by the title, he probably means the determinant of the matrix :)

Comment: @Anna-Banana Write the formulas for the three determinants and then the problem is easy...

Comment: @GitGud does it really matter?

Comment: @Tim Ahah, you're right.

Comment: @Anna-Banana, are you sure the second column of the second matrix is not $\,1,1,3\,$ ?

Comment: It is easy to express the second column of the new matrix as a linear combination of the second columns of the previous ones. Then use multilinearity of determinant.

Comment: Well @julien, it is easy to express it **now**, after the OP edited her/his question and changed the second determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multilinearity of the determinant (by columns), we get:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a&3&d\\b&5&e\\ c&7&f
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
a&1+2&d\\b&1+4&e\\ c&1+6&f
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
a&1&d\\b&1&e\\ c&1&f
\end{vmatrix}+2\begin{vmatrix}
a&1&d\\b&2&e\\ c&3&f
\end{vmatrix}=7+2\cdot 11=29$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** Use that the determinant is multilinear:

- Multiplying a column in the matrix by a scalar multiplies the determinant by the same amount. In symbols: $\det [a_1, \cdots, ca_r, \cdots, a_n] = c \det A$.
- It is linear in the columns. Explicitly (using [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)'s notation), we have $\det\begin{bmatrix} a_1, & \ldots, & b a_j + c v, & \ldots, a_n \end{bmatrix} = b \det(A) + c \det\begin{bmatrix} a_1, & \ldots, & v, & \ldots, a_n \end{bmatrix}$.